# Xrm.Page.data.getIsValid() return different values for users with different roles

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, xrm

I have a ribbon button "ABC" on Opportunity form.
OnClick of "ABC" following function is triggered:

```
function popup()
{
    if (!Xrm.Page.data.getIsValid()) return;
    -------
    -------
    -------
}
```

I have tested following steps.

If user has role other than system Administrator.

1. open opportunity record, click on "ABC" button, popup() function is triggered. `Xrm.Page.data.getIsValid()` return true
2. Open opportunity record, click on "ABC" button,Edit record, save record, popup() function is triggered.  `Xrm.Page.data.getIsValid()` return false

If user has role system Administrator.

1. open opportunity record, click on "ABC" button, popup() function is triggered. `Xrm.Page.data.getIsValid()` return true
2. Open opportunity record, click on "ABC" button,Edit record, save record, popup() function is triggered.  `Xrm.Page.data.getIsValid()` return true

Please help me why getIsValid() returns diffrent values if user is not administrator

Answer (score 1):

Where did you find `getIsValid()`? That doesn't appear in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481607.aspx). So I'm guessing its an internal and therefore unsupported function, e.g. you shouldn't expect it to work.

Suggest reworking the design using only functions listed on the MSDN.

Comment: Thanks a lot James, I am also thinking not to use this function further more due to the odd behaviour and due to this is an internal function.